# WebSphere http outbound socket configuration

Tags: websphere, connection, outbound

We are running a performance test on a WebSphere 8.5.5.1 application server that calls many external SOAP services.  Running netstat we notice that the server is only creating a max of 50 outbound connections.

We are trying to increase this value but cannot find the correct property.  We have increased the Default pool but this doesn't seem to apply.

The WebContainer pool size is also set to higher than 50 and we can see this pool grow.  Is there some hidden pool that is defaulting to 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure `com.ibm.websphere.webservices.http.maxConnection` property based on this:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/rwbs_httptransportprop.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, Marcin.